# Why is Data.Text.Lazy needed? Couldn't strict chunks of a lazy structure be made by a compiler optimizer?

Tags: haskell, compiler-optimization, ghc

I wonder whether a Haskell compiler optimizer couldn't generally split larger lazy data structures into smaller strict pieces to gain more performant programs.

For example, by `Data.Text.Lazy` we make the same behavior. Strict chunks of `Data.Text` in larger lazy structures. If this optimization would be possible, could we just use `String` instead with the same performance and make the code nicer?

Is there any conceptual/theoretical reason, why this optimization can't be made, or it is just practically so hard, nobody implemented it yet? Is it the current issue among GHC developers?

Comment: You're a bit too optimistic about the optimization capabilities even of modern optimizing compilers like GHC.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know. I would like to just understand, why am I so naive. I am missing something and I can't find out what it is.

Comment: I mean, it's just not an easy problem. You can't simply check “this is a `[Char]`, let's store it as packed UTF-16 in chunks” and be done with it. You need to also convert any code that ever uses the string in question, including library functions that may well be polymorphic on arbitrary lists; you need to take care for cases where you need lazyness on a granulary smaller than the chunk size; you need to ensure that no coercions happens where somebody assumes the type is representationally equal to `[Char]` and then the actual optimized type is forgotten, etc. etc..

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know about these problems. I am wondering, whether it is so hard problem, that community is strongly encouraged to migrate to Data.Text even through it might be solved in few years or whether it is theoretically unsolvable.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný The [earliest version of `text` on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.1) was uploaded in 2009 (although the earliest version of `base` is also 2009, so that might just be the age of Hackage). We've been using it over 12 years. If it was on the verge of going away  because it could be automatically implemented by the compiler optimizing from `String` people would be **extremely excited** (though probably more by the wider uses of such amazing technology) and you would easily be able to find references to it with trivial googling. It's not going anywhere soon.

Comment: So yes, it is such a hard problem that nobody expects it to be solved in a few years. Also you're *probably* better learning and coding in the language we have today, rather than one we *might* have years in the future. (I don't really know, but I suspect it might be unsolvable, in that it might be impossible to make it guarantee to always optimize enough for no one to need to use an explicitly chunked structure like `Text`, while also guaranteeing that there are no usages for `String` for which the optimization makes things worse).

Comment: @Ben In my case it isn't about learning a new language. Rather I want to avoid future changes in the code - I believe String will be supported in ether way, but I am worried, whether `Data.Text` won't be deprecated soon. But as I understand, this is not the case.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný The usual way people avoid changes to their code from a changing ecosystem is to pick versions of dependencies (copmiler, libraries, etc) and stick with them, avoiding updates released in future unless necessary. i.e. you stay locked to a *past* state of the ecosystem, rather than attempting to predict a *future* state and code for that. Even if the `text` library were to become unnecessary tomorrow, the versions already released will still exist and work. Nobody's going to force you to rewrite your code to use `String` in that hypothetical future.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that's the usual way. But I love being on the bleeding edge and it requires a lot of analysis before doing anything...it much easier to cause the harm, if you don't predict the future state correctly. - Eg. C++ If you can't predict and be prepared, what is in the mind of community, your application and its API might get easily broken by future releases of compiler, new optimization features, new standards, etc... But there is usually a way, how to avoid it. If eg. some library from boost will probably become a new standard, be sure to use it rather then the current official way.

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is, what is `Data.Text.Lazy` good for, if `String` structure using the compiler optimizations (if they exist) should behave just like it?

If `String` behaved just like `Data.Text.Lazy.Text`, then there would indeed be no point. But it doesn't, and there are no inklings that it might in the near future.

Comment: "no inklings that it might in the near future" - Are you sure about that? Nobody tries to solve vectorization problems which comes with usage of linked lists?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný It's practically impossible to be sure about any universal statement about people's mental states. There's just too many people. Nevertheless, I have not heard of any such efforts. (Also, I'm not convinced that vectorization is related to the optimization problem that needs to be solved for this.)

Comment: Why won't be vectorization related to this? If you want to do list vectorization without strict chunks list, you would have to do some crazy inlining, or accept performance penalties, which would come from repeted creating of a linked list from arrays. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný Your thinking is wrong. Your thinking shows that an optimization that causes strict chunks to be available would help with vectorization, not that vectorization is needed to cause strict chunks to be available. Additionally there seems to be an implicit assumption that vectorization is the only reason that having strict chunks available is nice, which isn't correct; it also significantly improves memory residency and cache locality for lots of non-parallel programs.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný It's probably *also* worth pointing out that the difference between `String` and lazy `Text` goes a bit farther than just making strict chunks. `Text` is also unpacked and uses a different encoding, and both actually turn out to matter for its performance benefits. Especially noticing that changing encoding is a good idea is kind of a lot to ask of a compiler.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Thanks. My hidden assumption was, that the only way to make vectorization reasonable as optimalization is usage of chunks....which is not true. /

Comment: "it also significantly improves memory residency and cache locality for lots of non-parallel programs." - Can you elaborate it more please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242237/discussion-between-premysl-sastny-and-daniel-wagner).